# adding function into notification

Tags: android, notifications

hello guys probably my question is pretty basic but since am a noob in android development have to ask it , i want to add an action inside a notification and am almost done with it by using this code

```
notification.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Decrease", pendingIntent);
```

but as you can see i added a `pendingIntent`in parameter and this `intent` is passing me to a particular activity (what it supposed to do so) but instead of passing the user to an activity i want to perform an action without opening the app how can i do this ?? and my action is for increasing a counterValue like performing `Counter++`

Answer (score 0):

Pending intent can only used as a intent, without such ability to run only a piece of code.
You can use a dummy activity to be opened on notification click and exits immediately after doing the jobs.

However, using activities can be annoying for the users as it flashes in and out on screen. So you might want to use [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to not interrupt users and do your job simultaneously.

In your case [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) seems to fit which can be used with ease.

Android document nicely describes a service's lifecycle and methods of it so it's worth a try.